# Are there any fonts that allow for the name of Hashem to be typed the way it is in Sephardi siddurim?

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, shemos-sacred-names, prayer-book

I'd like to be able to typeset various tefilos on my computer, so I'd like to be able to type the name of Hashem the way it appears in Sephardi siddurim, like this:

[image]

Are there any fonts that allow for that?

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I think it is. We have a number of questions such as, "Is there a computer program to do ..." This looks similar.

Comment: Offhand, maybe you can just take a pic of this style and paste it as a pic everywhere you need it? How complicated would that be?

Comment: The picture is too small for me to make out on my computer what the stuff under the _he_ is. Please make it larger and/or [add `alt` text](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3426) -- preferably both.

Comment: contact the guy who coded those tehillim. he must have used something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, here are screenshots of Windows Character Map showing DBS-Frank, DBS-Keren DBS-Stam, and DBS-Vilna:

[image: Windows Character Map]

Comment: great line 8 column 14 will result to a good use of this

Comment: @kouty What character is that?

Comment: Shekel Chadash שקל חדש

Comment: I'm not THAT technical. Where do you get these fonts? Any specific web site that has these for free download?

Comment: @DanF Some seem to be available [here](https://www.fontyukle.net/en/1,dbs).

Comment: These fonts aren't working. If I paste just that glyph, it's fine, but when I try to type in the font, it shows up as a generic Hebrew system font. I'm using Apple Pages 5.2.2